how to edit our own message subject in teams channel using power apps?
I have created one powerapps app which I will publish in channel and from that app I want to edit Subject of my messages. That I have send before. How can I do it?
I know that only the user which have sent the message can edit the message. That's what I want to do. I want the app user can edit his/her own message subject by app.

You should show your code and your effort to solve the issue, reporting what does not work as expected

Currently there is no such function available within PowerApps to update/edit posted message or its subject in Microsoft team's channel. https://i.sstatic.net/cwoluZxg.png

To better achieve your requirements, we recommend submitting this feature request through the Teams Feedback Portal. This is the best way to ensure your idea is considered for future updates.
